# Stop taking in text from textView

Tags: ios, swift, text, swift3, uitextview

I am working in swift 3. Is there any way to take text from a textView once and then prevent the program from taking data ever again? I gather text from a text view like such:

```
    let orig_hex_str = textView.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

But is there anyway that after I get the input one time to tell it to use that input forever and not to get any more text from a textView and/or not to change the data in that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable editing once you take values from textview

```
textView.isEditable = false
```